# How to disable expand in Virtualstringtree dblclick

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I want to implement other events in virtualstringtree dblcick, No need to expand/collapse in  dblcick, only need to use +/- to expand/collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this code *above* your form's definition in your .PAS source:

```
type   
  TVirtualStringTree = class(VirtualTrees.TVirtualStringTree)
                          procedure HandleMouseDblClick(var Message: TWMMouse; const HitInfo: THitInfo); override;
                       end;
```

and the implementation of the HandleMouseDblClick should be:

```
procedure TVirtualStringTree.HandleMouseDblClick(var Message: TWMMouse; const HitInfo: THitInfo);
begin
  DoNodeDblClick(HitInfo)
end;
```

It will then (only) call the OnNodeDblClick event handler on a DoubleClick event, where you can do what you need. You may need to investigate the HitInfo parameter to determine if a node was truly clicked (and not just the white area). I'll leave that up to you :-)

Comment: successful, thank you